What is the difference between alguno and algunos?
¿Alguno de vosotros conduce?
¿Algunos de vosotros conduce?
What is the difference? Both seem to mean "Do any of you guys drive?". Then what is the difference between using singular and plural?

It depends on how many drivers you need. Are you asking for a single driver (alguno) or you need more than one (algunos)? Also the verb tense should match the plural in the second option, it should be "conducís". In any case, second option sounds not idiomatic, on asking for multiple drivers, usually you ask: ¿Cuántos de vosotros conducís? And then you pick from the ones raising their hand the number you need.

@RubioRic My textbook said when you use alguno when both cantidad and identidad are not determined. Then unlike saying 'un', alguno would not necessarily demand only one. This fact makes me confused.

Just as is the case in English with "any" (or "some") and their compounds, in Spanish "alguno" can be used in questions in Spanish in the singular but an answer in the plural may be expected.
If we say:

Does any (one) of you drive?

it might be the case that there's more than just one driver. Same thing happens in Spanish:

¿Alguno de vosotros conduce? (in Argentina we say: ¿Alguno de ustedes conduce?)

One or more may say: I do, or one of them may answer: We all do, or Both of us do. In Spanish: Yo conduzco / Todos conducimos, o Nosotros dos conducimos.
If the plural is used in the question, the asker takes for granted that there is more than one driver:

Do any of you drive?

¿Algunos de vosotros/ustedes conducen?


